# Orchard CMS Custom Module Project File

Tags: orchardcms, orchardcms-1.6

I have an existing solution (multiple projects, one MVC web project) that I'm trying to wrap into an Orchard module.

All documentation says that the web csproj should be at the root under my module directory (eg Modules/MyModule/MyWeb.csproj).

However, I have an existing solution structure where the sln file sits at the top level and each csproj file (and project content) sits in its own directory (the standard solution structure when you build a multi-project app in Visual Studio).

Is there a way I can tell my Module.txt file that the Orchard Module csproj is under MyModule/MyWeb/MyWeb.csproj? I'd prefer to not restructure the whole solution.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

**Note:** As a point of clarification, it is not ~/Modules/MyModule/MyWeb.csproj but ~/Modules/MyModule/MyModule.csproj. The Folder name of the Module must match the file name of the project (before .csproj). This is enforced by the Dynamic Extension Loader, which requires ~/Module/{ModuleId}/{ModuleId}.csproj. (A similar approach is required for themes.)

The only potential way to do this is to write a custom module that follows the above that contains a custom loader. Within your module, create your own implementation of IExtensionLoader, and register it with Autofac. However, I don't know if it would work; I've never tried.

You will probably have an easier time reorganizing your solution.